# getting error in sql: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: sql

need help in fixing the error,trying to run a query and am getting the error Every derived table must have its own alias, below is the code:

```
$sql="SELECT trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2, status, COUNT(*) FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2 FROM tbl_main )
GROUP BY trouble_type_priority,category_1,category_2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your subquery an "alias", or name.

Notice the addition of `a` after your subquery:

```
$sql="SELECT trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2, status, COUNT(*) FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2 FROM tbl_main ) a
GROUP BY trouble_type_priority,category_1,category_2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need do add an alias to your subquery:

```
 $sql="SELECT trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2, status, COUNT(*)
       FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2
          FROM tbl_main) s
       GROUP BY trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
```

Please notice the 's' added after the SELECT ... FROM (....) s